# Get sql values and put in chart.js

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, charts, bar-chart

I have been trying to get values from sql and put it to chart.js.

What I have accomplished is getting the right query in displaying the right data.

I am using bar chart in chart.js to display how many people have birthdays in each month.

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM person WHERE MONTH( birthday ) = 02 //02 = February
```

I have seen a solution online but it is not for bar chart. Nevertheless, I tried it.

---

#### PHP code:

```
include('config.php');

$months = array("january", "february", "march", "april", "may", "june", "july", "august", "september", "october", "november", "december");
$monthvalues = array();
foreach ($months as $month) {
    $monthvalues[$month] = 0;
}

$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT birthday, count(*) FROM person group by birthday;");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    $monthvalues[$row[0]] = (int)$row[1];
}

print (json_encode($monthvalues));
```

---

#### JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    new Chart($("#canvas_bar").get(0).getContext("2d")).Bar({
        labels: [<?=json_encode($months);?>],
        datasets: [{
            fillColor: "#03586A", //rgba(151,187,205,0.5)
            strokeColor: "#03586A", //rgba(151,187,205,0.8)
            highlightFill: "#066477", //rgba(151,187,205,0.75)
            highlightStroke: "#066477", //rgba(151,187,205,1)
            data: [<?=json_encode(array_values($monthvalues));?>]
        }]
    }, {
        tooltipFillColor: "rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.55)",
        responsive: true,
        barDatasetSpacing: 6,
        barValueSpacing: 5
    });
});
```

My code returns `NaN`.

How can I properly do it? Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Can you post the raw output of `data: [<?=json_encode(array_values($monthvalues));?>]`?

Comment: Executing everything would simply show.. 'NaN'. :(

Comment: Can you view the generated source of your page and paste the raw output of that line? That is most likely where your issue is coming from

Comment: I tried printing it after the while code and this is the output:

Comment: l":0,"may":0,"june":0,"july":0,"august":0,"september":0,"october":0,"november":0,"december":0,"1992-12-14":1,"1997-10-23":1,"1999-07-20":1,"2002-08-30":1,"2003-07-31":1,"2003-08-10":1,"2004-05-13":1,"2004-05-19":1,"2006-06-21":1,"2007-07-24":1,"2007-12-23":1,"2008-11-20":1,"2009-08-14":1,"2009-12-26":1,"2015-11-24":1,"2016-02-01":3,"2016-02-02":1,"2016-02-03":1,"2016-02-04":1,"2016-03-31":1}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like at least part of the problem is that you are nesting your label and data arrays when they should just be a single dimension. Remove the outer brackets from your `json_encode` calls:

```
var barChartData = {
    labels: <?=json_encode($months);?>,
    datasets: [
            {
                fillColor: "#03586A", //rgba(151,187,205,0.5)
                strokeColor: "#03586A", //rgba(151,187,205,0.8)
                highlightFill: "#066477", //rgba(151,187,205,0.75)
                highlightStroke: "#066477", //rgba(151,187,205,1)
                data: <?=json_encode(array_values($monthvalues));?>
        }
    ]
};
```

I'm not sure about your MySQL table structure, but it might be better to just get the month name and the count:

```
"SELECT LOWER(MONTHNAME(birthday)), count(*) FROM person GROUP BY LOWER(MONTHNAME(birthday))"
```

That will give you output like:

```
april   53
august  8
december    4
february    75
march   56
may 2
november    13
october 1
september   11
```

You could update your PHP to give you a more structured output like:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT birthday, count(*) FROM person group by birthday;");
$output = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    array_push($output, $row);
}

print (json_encode($output));
```

That will output `[{ "january": 53 }, { "february": 23 }, ....etc]`, then your javascript would change to:

```
var barChartData = {
    labels: <?=json_encode(array_keys($output));?>,
    datasets: [
            {
                fillColor: "#03586A", //rgba(151,187,205,0.5)
                strokeColor: "#03586A", //rgba(151,187,205,0.8)
                highlightFill: "#066477", //rgba(151,187,205,0.75)
                highlightStroke: "#066477", //rgba(151,187,205,1)
                data: <?=json_encode(array_values($output));?>
        }
    ]
};
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/obmKer